# Why would methanol and water be used for an aqueous layer in a separating funnel compared to just water?

Tags: extraction

I have a protocol for separating an inorganic component from an organic mixture, which asks for the mixture to be suspended in methanol and water and then doing an extraction with hexane. I understand that this allows separation of polar components from non-polar components. I am wondering what use methanol in water has in liquid-liquid extractions compared to just using water? My only ideas are: lowering the polarity of water, increasing the density, or somehow allowing some compounds to collect at the interface.

Comment: Lowering the surface tension, maybe?

Comment: @IvanNeretin what does a lower surface tension do?

Comment: Lower surface tension would make it easier to get good phase intermixing when agitating the mixture.  Droplets of water/MeOH in hexanes would be smaller, last (slightly) longer, and better facilitate the _equilibrium_ partitioning of solutes between the two phases.

Comment: Another idea: the methanol is easier to remove than water, so after the extraction is done and the inorganic component is in the aqueous phase, the time & energy required to remove all the solvent is lower than if 100% water was used instead.